# Variadic symbols in first-order logic

Tags: logic, soft-question

Normally the syntax of a first-order language is defined roughly like this:

1. Variables and constant symbols are terms
2. If $f$ is an $n$-ary function symbol and $t_1, \ldots, t_n$ are terms, then $f(t_1, \ldots, t_n)$ is a term
3. If $P$ is an $n$-ary predicate symbol and $t_1, \ldots, t_n$ are terms, then $P(t_1, \ldots, t_n)$ is a formula
4. The usual definitions for the connectives and quantifiers, etc...

What if we instead loosened the definition like this:

1. Variables and constant symbols are terms
2. If $f$ is a function symbol and $t_1, \ldots, t_n$ are terms, then $f(t_1, \ldots, t_n)$ is a term
3. If $P$ is a predicate symbol and $t_1, \ldots, t_n$ are terms, then $P(t_1, \ldots, t_n)$ is a formula
4. The usual definitions for the connectives and quantifiers, etc...

Essentially we no longer check the arity of a function or predicate symbol when validating that a formula is syntactically correct, allowing us to write formulas like this:

$\forall x,y,z. (P(x) \iff P(y,z)) \implies f(x) = f(y,z)$

Then, instead of each function symbol $f$ having an associated arity $n$ and a fixed interpretation $I(f): D^n \to D$, each *occurence* of $f$ with $n$ arguments $f_n$ is given an interpretation $I(f_n): D^n \to D$, and similarly for the predicate symbols.

My question is this: is there any reason to do this? Adding restrictions to the syntax of first-order logic can sometimes make theories more convenient to write, such as with many-sorted or order-sorted logic. Does loosening the syntax like this gain us anything?

Comment: I'm not sure if I have understood the question correctly. If $f$ is the binary function symbol $+$ in your example above, what does $f(x)$ mean?

Comment: @Rick In this version of FOL, function symbols do not have an associated arity. There is no binary function symbol +, there is just _the_ function symbol +, which can be written with two or three or however many arguments. For example, it would be perfectly legal to write $\forall x. +(x, 0) = +(x)$. The first occurrence of + has two arguments, so it would be interpreted by a function $I(+_2): D^2 \to D$. The second occurence of + has 1 argument, so it would be interpreted by a function $I(+_1): D \to D$. My question is if doing this has any practical applications.

Comment: @Kalvehoof I don't think this gives you any additional expressivity: You could always rewrite expressions in your version of FOL to an equivalent formula in FOL where you replace the function expression $f(t_1, \ldots, t_n)$ with an expression $f_n(t_1, \ldots, t_n)$, i.e., you replace each function and predicate symbol with a countable family of symbols, one for each arity.

Comment: @JohannesKloos Yeah, I figured it wouldn't change the strength of the logic, I was just wondering if there were situations where it was syntactically more convenient to define things this way. For instance, many-sorted FOL is equivalent to regular FOL with monadic predicates for each sort and all quantification over sorts $S$ rewritten as $\forall x. S(x) \implies \ldots$ and $\exists x. S(x) \wedge \ldots$ The many-sorted version is often more convenient to write and read though.

Comment: The main impetus behind this question was that I noticed people usually write the signature of a first order theory as just a tuple of the predicate and function symbols when formally the signature should include the arity of those symbols as well, and I wanted to make the informal practice make sense formally.

Comment: So your idea is essentially to allow overloading of non-logical symbols, using the same function/predicate name for interpretations with different arity?

Comment: But the question is: if $+_2$ (the binary one) has a different interpretation from $+_1$ (the unary one), why not use different symbols? What is the benefit of the ambiguity ?